# What can F0 do with custom translator?

Tags: azure, microsoft-translator

The Azure F0 (free) plan allow users to train their own model but not allowing them to deploy and use the model trained. So what is the purpose of allowing users to train if it could not be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could see the result of your training, as long as your training data is less than 2 million characters. The result includes a BLEU score, and the translation of your test set.